# Cell selection style in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

By default there is three selection style in iPhone - table view.

gray - blue - none.

I don't need gray or blue.

I want to set my custom.

For example, in normal situation a cell should have "aaaa.png" background, and selected cell should have "bbbbb.png" background.

I have tried to apply cell.backgroundView & cell.selectedBackground view. However it isn't working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three lines of code here, but you don't need an image!

```
UIView *selectedBackgroundViewForCell = [UIView new];
[selectedBackgroundViewForCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
theCell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundViewForCell;
```

Comment: working fine... one issue with it .. when I am using grouped table then its first row become rounded but on selection it not become rounded

Answer (score 6):

**Here's one way to do it with only 1 line of code:**

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pink.png"]] autorelease];
```

> obviously you'll need to make the image.

Answer (score 3):

I tried following & it worked.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    XML_FitnessPrograms *t=[arrayPrograms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell=((indexPath.row%2)==0) ? 
    [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier program_name:t.program_name alterNate:NO indexPath:indexPath] :
    [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier program_name:t.program_name alterNate:YES indexPath:indexPath] ;
    CGRect a=CGRectMake(8, 0, 300, 44);
    UIImageView *aImg=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:a];
    UIImageView *bImg=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:a];
    aImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"white-rect-tab.png"]; //arrow.png
    bImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"white-rect-tab-copy.png"];
    [aImg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [bImg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    cell.backgroundView=aImg;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView=bImg;
    [aImg release];
    [bImg release];
}
return cell;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)getCellContentView:(NSString*)cellIdentifier program_name:(NSString*)program_name alterNate:(BOOL)alterNate indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell; UILabel *tmp;
    CGRect label1Frame=CGRectMake(5, 0, 260, 44);
    cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.frame=CGRectMake(8, 0, 280, 44);
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    tmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label1Frame]; 
    tmp.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(9.0/255.0) green:(68.0/255) blue:(85.0/255) alpha:1.0];
    [tmp setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:15]];  
        tmp.text=program_name;                   
        [tmp setShadowColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    tmp.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tmp]; [tmp release];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
    return cell;
}
```